# Apache-Ignite integration as Hibernate 2nd level cache: What is the best way to look into ignite cache?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, caching, gridgain, ignite

Can someone please let me know the best way to check if the Apache-Ignite Hibernate 2nd level cache is working ? and How ?

eg.
1. VisualVM
2. Hibernate statistics logs

I have worked with EHcache and i was able to configure a Viusual VM Mbean to get statistics as below:

```
<bean id="cacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/spring/ehcache.xml" />
    <property name="shared" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- JMX for ehcache -->

<bean id="managementService" class="net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="dispose">

    <constructor-arg ref="cacheManager" />
    <constructor-arg ref="mbeanServer" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg index="4" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg index="5" value="true" />

</bean>

<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Also , Hibernate statistics printout PUT/HIT/MISS in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite supports JMX as well. To enable full statistics for the cache add the following properties to its configuration:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <property name="managementEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

JMX service itself is enabled by default. Locate this line in the node log to identify the port number (49113 in this example):

```
Remote Management [restart: on, REST: on, JMX (remote: on, port: 49113, auth: off, ssl: off)]
```